# Why does the validation email returns an error while registering it doesn't?

Tags: php, database, validation, email, controller

I am developing a Register/Login system with validation. Registering system is working well. For example, when I register the same email twice, the following message appears:

> Email already registered!

However, when I log-in with the same e-mail and password, an error occurs. The following message appears as a validation error:

> Email not registered!

Even if the email is registered in DB.

Code for e-mail validation:

```
<?php

public function validateEmail($par)
{
    if (filter_var($par, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $this->setErro("Invalid Email!");
        return false;
    }
}

public function validateIssetEmail($email, $action = null)
{
    $b = $this->cadastro->getIssetEmail($email);

    if ($action == null) {
        if ($b > 0) {
            $this->setErro("Email already registered!");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        if ($b > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->setErro("Email not registered!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Code for login controller:

```
<?php

$validate = new Classes\ClassValidate();
$validate->validateFields($_POST);
$validate->validateEmail($email);
$validate->validateIssetEmail($email,"login");
$validate->validateStrongSenha($senha);
$validate->validateSenha($email,$senha);
var_dump($validate->getErro());
```

Code for class login:

```
<?php

namespace Models;

class ClassLogin extends ClassCrud
{

    # Returns user data
    public function getDataUser($email)
    {
        $b = $this->selectDB(
            "*",
            "users",
            "where email=?",
            array(
                $email
            )
        );
        $f = $b->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $r = $b->rowCount();
        return $arrData = [
            "data" => $f,
            "rows" => $r
        ];
    }
}
```

My `getIssetEmail` method exists on Register code only.

```
# Check directly at the bank if the email is registered     
public function getIssetEmail($email)
{         
    $b = $this->selectDB(             
        "*",             
        "users",             
        "where email=?",             
        [                 
            $email             
        ]        
    );         
    return $r = $b->rowCount(); // returns the amount of rows in the search     
}
```

And ClassPassword

```
<?php

namespace Classes;

use Models\ClassLogin;

class ClassPassword
{

    private $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new ClassLogin();
    }


    # Create password's hash to save in DB
    public function passwordHash($senha)
    {
        return password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    }


    # Verify if password's hash is correct
    public function verifyHash($email, $senha)
    {
        $hashDb = $this->db->getDataUser($email);
        return password_verify($senha, $hashDb["data"]["senha"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your `getIssetEmail ` method code.

Comment: my `getIssetEmail` method exists on Register code only.

`#Check directly at the bank if the email is registered
    public function getIssetEmail($email){
        $b=$this->selectDB(
            "*",
            "users",
            "where email=?",
            array(
                $email
            )
        );
        return $r=$b->rowCount();//returns the amount of rows in the search
    }`

Comment: I will put it as a answer

Comment: use `print_r($b);` in `getDataUser` and `getIssetEmail`. what you see?

Comment: You mean, put it as if it were on the page on which methods are?

Comment: Because this system is similar to a MVC... so it doesn't work.

Comment: print_r work in methods. for example: `print_r($b); return $r=$b->rowCount();`

Comment: oh, ok. I will try

Comment: Nothing appear when I try in the register file (getIssetEmail), but in login file the following message appear

`Fatal error: Cannot declare class Models\ClassLogin, because the name is already in use in C:\xampp\htdocs\login_AMUBA\models\ClassLogin.php on line 27`

Comment: I edited my answer including a new part of the code, I think this might help you help me.

Comment: You use `Classes` name twice. you cannot use similar namespace name

Comment: Where? I noticed that too...

Comment: some news... print_r($b) showed this

`PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => select * from users where email=? ) `

Comment: Are you sure you select return anything?!

Comment: What do you mean?